# SELECT * FROM table WHERE column = ??? in PHP with unknown number of values for?

Tags: php, sql, select

I'm trying to show some stuff from my database. There's this column called Genre which can be one out of five different values. Now I want to show only the data for the genres the user has selected by checking checkboxes. The user can choose more than one genre. I know how to show one, two or three genres by using WHERE... AND... but I don't know how many genres the user will select! This is what I use to show data when a checkbox 'actie' is checked:

```
if (isset($_GET["actie"]))
    {
    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT ProductID,Afbeelding,Product,Prijs,Beschrijving FROM Producten WHERE Genre='Actie' order by Product ASC");
    }
```

How can I do this for multiple checkboxes so that it shows all data for when for instance 'actie' and 'sports' are checked? I'm confused since I don't know how many checkboxes a user will select, none, one, two, three, four or five.
Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Use [`IN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) (*and* placeholders) for any-of logic . You'll need to dynamically build the IN structure - such as "X IN (?,?,?)", for the correct number of values from the user. Similar approaches can be used for any arbitrary structure (ANDs, perhaps) required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that all your checkboxes have the same name property followed by []
i.e

```
<input type="checkbox" name="mycheckbox[]" value="gen1">
<input type="checkbox" name="mycheckbox[]" value="gen2">
<input type="checkbox" name="mycheckbox[]" value="gen3">
```

Then when you submit the form, all selected checkboxes with the same common name will be available as `$_POST['mycheckbox']` or `$_GET['mycheckbox']`; and their corresponding values will be gen1,gen2 or gen3 depending on what you set in the value field.

```
$genres = $_POST['mycheckbox'];//creates an array of selected checkboxes values gen1,gen2,gen3
```

Then use MySQL WHERE IN clause. You will have to convert the array to a string of 'gen1,gen2,..' by using `implode()`.

WHERE IN correct syntax: `SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE Genre IN ('gen1','gen2','gen3',...)`

```
if (isset($_GET["actie"])) 
    {

    $genres_str = "'" .implode( "','" ,$genres ) ."'";//converts the array into 'gen1,gen2,gen3,..'

    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT ProductID,Afbeelding,Product,Prijs,Beschrijving FROM Producten WHERE Genre IN (". $genres_str .") order by Product ASC");

   //don't forget to execute the query

    }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Great help so far! At least now I know what the basic idea is. One problem though, it doesn't show anything at all when I check one or multiple boxes. I think this is because implode(',', $genres) creates the string: gen1,gen2,gen3,... instead of the string: 'gen1','gen2','gen3',...   This way it says WHERE Genre in (gen1,gen2,gen3) seeing it as one value which just happens to have commas in it. Or am I saying something very stupid?

Comment: @DeEerlijkeDame You need to set a value to each checkbox. I will edit my answer to include it.

Comment: @DeEerlijkeDame it should work now. If you are having problems, try setting the values to numeric only (1,2,3 instead of gen1,gen2,gen3) and matching it against a genre id not a genre name.

Comment: Each checkbox does have a value, the corresponding value in the column in question. So those would be gen1, gen2, ... in this example

Comment: try to use var_dump on $_POST['mycheckbox']. BTW in the code you put, you are not executing the query so I am assuming you did not forget that...

Comment: When I check three random boxes, var_dump gives me: array(3) { [0]=> string(5) "Actie" [1]=> string(8) "Avontuur" [2]=> string(4) "Race" }    If I remove the dots ('.') in WHERE Genre IN (". $genres_str ."), then I do get results when only one box was checked.

Comment: And yes, I do excecute the query

Comment: `$genres_str = "'" .implode( "','" ,$genres ) ."'";`

Comment: Try adding single quotes (as both you and @Uours suggested)